# Sum of model methods django

Tags: python, django, model

I'm trying to get the sum of some of my model methods and display them on a results page. I'm not sure how possible it is to get this done in my views.py. I get the following error when I run the server.

Unsupported operand type(s) for + 'method' and 'method'

1. models.py

```
class Organization(ModelFieldRequiredMixin, models.Model):
        exist = models.BooleanField(help_text='Does organization exist physically?')
        blacklist = models.BooleanField(help_text='Has organization previously been blacklisted by a national authority, funder or fund manager?')
        grant_amount = MoneyField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, help_text='Total amount of grant(s) from largest donor to organization ')
        estimatedAnnual_budget = models.IntegerField(help_text='Estimated annual budget of the organization (inclusive of the largest funder), in US Dollars')

class Scores(ModelFieldRequiredMixin, models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)


    # Section1 - ORGANIZATIONAL BACKGROUND

    def exist_score(self):
        if self.organization.exist == True:
            self.score=0.1
            return self.score #The higher score

        else:
            score=0.1
            return self.score #The lower score

    def accessibility_score(self):
        if self.organization.accessibility == True:
            self.score=5
            return self.score

        else:
            score=0
            return self.score

    def blacklist_score(self):
        if self.organization.blacklist == True:
            self.score=0
            return self.score

        else:
            score=0
            return self.score

    # Section2 - PREVIOUS GRANTS & PERFORMANCE
    def grant_amount_score(self):
        if self.organization.grant_amount >= 2000000:
            self.score=3.5
            return self.score

        else:
            score=0
            return self.score

    def estimatedAnnual_budget_score(self):
        if self.organization.estimatedAnnual_budget == True:
            self.score=2
            return self.score

        else:
            score=0.1
            return self.score
```

2. Views.py

```
def results_view(request):  
    scores=Scores()

    previous_implementation = scores.exist_score + scores.accessibility_score + scores.blacklist_score + scores.grant_amount_score + scores.estimatedAnnual_budget_score
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
previous_implementation = scores.exist_score() + scores.accessibility_score() + scores.blacklist_score() + scores.grant_amount_score() + scores.estimatedAnnual_budget_score()
```